# "Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _main" still exists

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lnk2001

I know similar question is already been made but none of the answers helped me.

I get this error :

**MSVCRT.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _main**

I am using VS17. I created a Wizard Console Application and a Static Lib.

My A.cpp also looks like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"

namespace img{
    int main(int argc, char* argv[]{
        ...
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I tried changing the Properties of the Project as many suggested but everything looks fine.

Comment: Don't put main in a namespace.

Comment: You should not put main in a namespace, see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956678/main-in-namespace

Comment: IMHO, there is nothing wrong with `img::main()` except it doesn't provide the required entry point for program. You could add another function `int main(int argc, char **argv) { return img::main(argc, argv); }` to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Main needs to be defined in the global namespace as per conversion.